# What is the name of someone who was something before you?

Tags: single-word-requests

I've completely forgotten the word you say when someone had your job or something before you, and then you took over.

I'm trying to write a History Essay and my sentence is

> The legacy of German's defeat in World War One hung in the air for years after Hitler's **______**'s signed the Treaty Of Versailles

I keep thinking its something like *oppressor* or something but I'm stuck.

Comment: Are you looking for *predecessor?*

Comment: I am not a native English speaker, so this is question for people who are more fluent than me: Is the wort [antecedent](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/antecedent) used in different meaning?

Comment: @Martin: yes, it does have a different meaning. *Antecedent* can mean 'ancestor' though not the normal meaning; but that is as close as it comes.

Answer (score 40):

[**Predecessor**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/predecessor?q=predecessor): A person who held a job or office before the current holder.

Answer (score 1):

With respect to the office:

> **[Prepossessor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/prepossessor)** n. One who possesses, or occupies, previously. --R. Brady.

With respect to the person:

> **[Antecessor](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Antecessor)** a person who goes before; predecessor.

Comment: Wouldn't *Hitler's prepossessor* be a person who previously possessed Hitler?  That doesn't seem to be what the asker wants.

Comment: hmm, isn't a preposessor the reverse of a repossessor? Sounds more like something for exorcists...

Comment: I agree with @NateEldredge you would write "...Germany's Prepossessor..." otherwise you are implying it's the person who previously possessed Hitler.  my $.02

Answer (score -2):

antecedents

I have to enter a minimum of thirty characters, so this should satisfy the requirement.

Comment: Hi Tom, welcome to the site!  This is a good suggestion, but the preferred way of rounding out the 30-character minimum when answering a single-word-request question is to provide a definition (and a link to the source of that definition).  :-)